# Deleting values from dataset

Tags: c#, dataset

I am trying to delete the data present in the dataset with following code:

```
stateflowDataSet dsobject = new stateflowDataSet();
stateflowDataSetTableAdapters.dbo_statetableTableAdapter statetableadapter = new         stateflowDataSetTableAdapters.dbo_statetableTableAdapter();
statetableadapter.Fill(dsobject.dbo_statetable);
dsobject.dbo_statetable.Clear();
statetableadapter.Update(dsobject);
```

But after this line when use `statetableadapter.Fill(dsobject.dbo_statetable);` the data is still retained.

Is the way in which I am clearing the data right?

Is there any other problem with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing `DataRows` from a `DataTable` does not mean that you'll delete them from your DBMS. The opposite is true, actually you're preventing them from being deleted even if you would have called `DataRow.Delete()` before.

The reason is: only `DataRows` that belong to a `DataTable` can be deleted by

```
DataAdapter.Update(table)
```

This will delete every row in the table with [`DataRowState=Deleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate.aspx).
Therefor you need to use the [`Delete` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete.aspx).

```
foreach(DataRow row in dsobject.dbo_statetable.Rows)
{
    row.Delete();
}
statetableadapter.Update(dsobject.dbo_statetable);
```

You could do it also in one batch which would be more efficient, therefor you need to set the DataAdapter's [`UpdateBatchSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.updatebatchsize.aspx) to 0(unlimited).

Another way would to delete all rows is to use a simple `SqlCommand` with CommandText `DELETE FROM Table`:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["con"]))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Table";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    int numberDeleted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  // all rows deleted
}
```

Now you need to remove(not delete, what is the core of your question) the rows from the `DataTable` manually since you've also deleted them *manually* in the database:

```
dsobject.dbo_statetable.Clear();
```

Comment: foreach(DataRow row in dsobject.dbo_statetable.Rows)
{
    row.Delete();
} 
will not work as the local variable  'row' is only deleted , it has to be 'dbo_statetable.Row[row_number]'. 
Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Let me try re-wording Tims answer a little.  I used `DataSet`s alot when they were popular, and was confused with their 'magic'...

`Dataset` contains copy of the data from the database + your updates on the data since data is fetched from the database.

`Update()` method on the `DataAdapter` with your dataset isn't magic, it goes through your tables in the dataset, and in tables it scan rows.  It will:

- use `DeleteCommand` if row is marked for deletion
- use `UpdateCommand` if row is marked for update

Former is the case when you delete a row with `Delete()` method, and later is the case when you update some cell in the row.

You will learn much about the process if you observe `RowState` property of each row in the dataset tables.